# Symfony2: Key no exists in array [twig]

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

I want show the numbers of the elements in a array, but I have this problem

> Key "idTipoFarmaco" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
>   10, 11, 12" does not exist in
>   FarmacoBundle:Default:chartTipos.html.twig at line 17

Template

```
{% block artic %}

{{ entities.idTipoFarmaco.nombreFarmaco|length}}

{% endblock %}
```

Function

```
public function chartTiposFAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('::Entity')->findAll();



    return $this->render('::chartTipos.html.twig', array(
    'entities' => $entities

    ));

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Could you please explain further? Could you show us line 17 of chartTipos.html.twig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment on Jonathan (In which you explain that you want to count elements in the entities array which meet certain requirements) I would say you have to apply a filter before getting the length of the array.

See [the Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) about how to create a custom filter.

First create a Twig extention class:

```
namespace Foo\BarBundle\Twig;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

class YourTwigFiltersExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('filterType', array($this, 'filterType')),
        );
    }

    public function filterType(Collection $entities, $type)
    {
        return $entities->filter(function ($e) use ($type) {
            return $e->getType() == $type; // Replace this by your own check.
        });
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'your_twig_filters';
    }
}
```

Then register your extension as a service in services.yml (or your xml):

```
foobar.twig.filters_extension:
    class: Foo\BarBundle\Twig\YourTwigFiltersExtension
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

And use it as follows in your templates:

```
{% block artic %}

{{ entities|filterType('dog')|length }}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

update your template to be:

```
{% block artic %}

{{ entities|length }}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the post, i want show the elements of a specific type.

Example: 

100 animals elements in array is == {{ entities|length }}

but

I need show the 50 dogs

Comment: Your array is numeric, which means you'd need to do, {{ entities[0]|length }} could you perhaps post a sample of what your array is by doing a var_export($entities) on the php side.

Comment: in the end I resolved using match and length in javascript. Thanks for help !